# Exercise (Lemma 5.1) from Algebraic Geometry II by Mumford, Oda

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

I don't know how to solve an exercise I found in
a penultimate draft of [Algebraic Geometry II](https://www.dam.brown.edu/people/mumford/alg_geom/papers/AGII.pdf)  by
David Mumford and Tadao Oda on page 332.

[image]

In this chapter the ring $R$ is assumed to be local Artin ring
with maximal ideal $M$ and residue field $k= R/M$. The ideal $I \subset R$
has moreover the property $I \cdot M= 0$ (see page 327 for prelimnary assumptions)
In this exercise the
$R$ algebras $A$ and $B$ are assumed as I can see so far to be arbitrary.

on surjective (that's simple): $B$ is generated by $image(A) + I \cdot B = image(A)+
I \cdot (image(A) + I \cdot B) = image(A) + I \cdot image(A)$ because
$I^2 \subset I \cdot M =0$.

On the other hand I have no idea how to show that $A \to B$ injective and how to bring
flatness of $B$ over $R$ into the game.

Comment: Please do not rely on images: they are not searchable, and many screen readers cannot process them, making your post inaccessible to those who use them. Your post should be self-contained enough that it can be understood without having to be able to read the image posted.

Comment: thank you for the advise, above I added now a link to the complete book

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $z \in B$. Then there exists $x \in A$ such that $\phi(a) \in b+IB$. Let $t \in M$, then $\phi(ta) \in tb +IMB=tb$, so that $\phi(MA)=MB$. It follows that $B=IB +\phi(A) \subset MB+\phi(A)=M\phi(A)+\phi(A)=\phi(A)$ and $\phi$ is surjective, of kernel $K$.

$B/IB=(A/K)/(IA/K)=(A/IA+K)$, so that $K \subset IA$ so $MK=0$.

Now, $A/K$ is flat over $R$, and $0 \rightarrow K \rightarrow A \rightarrow A/K\rightarrow 0$ is exact, so it remains exact when tensored by anything.

So consider the morphism of complexes from $0 \rightarrow J \otimes K \rightarrow J \otimes A \rightarrow J \otimes (A/K) \rightarrow 0$ to $0 \rightarrow JK \rightarrow JA \rightarrow J(A/K) \rightarrow 0$ (where $J$ is any proper ideal of $R$). The former sequence is exact, the second sequence is exact except maybe in $JA$, and the vertical arrows are surjective (and an isomorphism for the $A/K$ one).

Diagram chasing shows that the second sequence is exact, but $JK \subset MIA=0$ so that $JA \cong J(A/K)$. In particular, with $J=I$, $IA \rightarrow I(A/K)=IA/K$ is an isomorphism so that $K=0$.

Comment: Why $B=A/K$ flat implies that the sequence $0 \rightarrow K \rightarrow A \rightarrow A/K\rightarrow 0$ stays exact after tensored by 'everything'? Why is this an imediate consequence of flatness of $A/K$? The characterization of flatness I know is that tensor every exact sequence *by* $A/K$ stay exact.

Comment: That’s an algebraic lemma. Conceptually, it’s because you can write the $Tor$ long exact sequence and $Tor$ is symmetric so $Tor(M,N)=0$ if $M$ or $N$ is flat. An elementary proof is as follows: let $0 \rightarrow A \rightarrow B \rightarrow C \rightarrow 0$ $(S)$ be an exact sequence with $C$ flat. We want to tensor it with $D$. Write $0 \rightarrow E \rightarrow F \rightarrow D \rightarrow 0$ exact with $F$ free, consider the exact diagram of complexes $S \otimes E \rightarrow S \otimes F \rightarrow S \otimes D \rightarrow 0$. Diagram chase and the flatness of $C$ show $S \otimes D$ exact.

Comment: yes, I see, everything is clear now, thank you. Alternatively 
one could also apply snake lemma to map of complexes $T \otimes A \to T \otimes B$
where sequence $(T)$ is your 
$0 \rightarrow E \rightarrow F \rightarrow D \rightarrow 0$.

Comment: You’re welcome! (You’d need to check that $E \otimes B \rightarrow F \otimes B$ is injective though, no?)

Comment: yes, I think the argument is that $0 \to E \to F$ splits ($F$ free) and tensor with something preserves splitting, but splitting of $E \otimes B \rightarrow F \otimes B$ implies that it's injective, I think that should work, right? Do you see another (maybe shorter) argument?

Comment: I’m not convinced that $0 \rightarrow E \rightarrow F$ should split, even though $F$ is free. That would mean that any exact sequence with free center term splits and that’s just false (imagine a maximal ideal of $R=\mathbb{Z}_p[[t]]$ plunged into $R$).

Comment: yes you are right, I think the core problem in your example (and why my splitting 'argument' fails) is that $R$ may have not enough free generators (namely only $1$) but the maximal ideal has more then one generator. hhhm I have to think a while about injectivity of $E \otimes B \rightarrow F \otimes B$...

Comment: I think I have figured it out, in my last idea I saw a 'wrong' snake
(indeed it seems to be no reason why $E \otimes B \rightarrow F \otimes B$
should be injective). Instead we should apply snake lemma to
$S \otimes E \rightarrow S \otimes F$ and flatness of $C$ implies
$E \otimes C \rightarrow F \otimes C$ is injective so it's kernel is trivial